Word Macro - Superscripting all footnote numbers at the footnote-section at the bottom of the page
I'd like a macro in Office Word which superscripts all footnote numbers at the footnote-section at the bottom of the page.
Note: It's the footnote numbers at the bottom of the page I want superscripted, not the footnote numbers in the main text. See illustration below.
This post provides a seemingly key hint. But it's slightly off-topic. Sadly, I cannot reverse-engingeer this to work for me, nor does AI manage. Here's the helpful bit, from user Timothy Rylatt:

A Word document is constructed from a number of Story Ranges, one of which is the Footnotes Story. To make the footnote number non-superscript just in the footnotes you can execute a find and replace in the Footnotes Story as below.

Sub ApplyChicagoStyle()
   With ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdFootnotesStory).Find
      .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleFootnoteReference)
      .Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleFootnoteText)
      .Replacement.Font.Superscript = False
      .Format = True
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   End With
End Sub

Illustration of wrong format:


Main Text with in-text footnote numbers



1 [non-supercripted, at-bottom footnote number] footnote bottom-text


ChatGPT and CoPilot got pretty close. Below are their macros for inspiration. But both failed because they superscripted the footnote text at the bottom, and not the numbers themselves. However, these AI managed to write macros which correctly superscripted footnotes in the main text. Perhaps there is some different formatting in the footnote section at the bottom of the page, which throws them off?
ChatGPT:
Sub SuperscriptFootnoteNumbers()
    Dim footnote As Footnote
    Dim fnRange As Range
    
    ' Loop through each footnote in the document
    For Each footnote In ActiveDocument.Footnotes
        ' Get the range of the footnote's number (not the text)
        Set fnRange = footnote.Range
        
        ' Superscript the first character, which is the footnote number
        fnRange.Font.Superscript = True
    Next footnote
End Sub

CoPilot:
Sub SuperscriptFootnoteNumbersInText()
    Dim footnote As Footnote
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    For Each footnote In ActiveDocument.Footnotes
        Set rng = footnote.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range
        i = 1
        Do While IsNumeric(Mid(rng.Text, i, 1))
            rng.Characters(i).Font.Superscript = True
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    Next footnote
End Sub


So why don't you use Timothy Rylatt's script? Just change .Replacement.Font.Superscript = False into .Replacement.Font.Superscript = True. (The AI generated scripts are useless.)

And leave out the .Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleFootnoteText), otherwise your macro will ony work once...

Thanks for your reply! I don't use his script, because I want only to change the superscripting, not apply the rest of the changes his script also makes (because it's a script which applies a whole style to footnotes, if I understand it correctly). I don't understand enough to copy only that relevant part from Rylatt, and still have a usable script.

Simple as:
Sub ApplySuperscriptToFootnoteReference()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For i = 1 To .Footnotes.Count
    .Footnotes(i).Range.Paragraphs.First.Range.Words.First.Style = wdStyleFootnoteReference
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

If someone has messed with the Footnote Reference Style, either fix that or use:
    .Footnotes(i).Range.Paragraphs.First.Range.Words.First.Font.Superscript = True


That worked, thanks! Saved me a lot of hours manually superscripting footnotes...
Optional question: out of curiosity, why did this script work where the others didn't -- i.e. what does this script do differently?

Without going through all the AI versions, Timothy's didn't work because someone had appparently removed the Footnote Reference Style from the Footnote References in the footer.

It is as simple as:
Sub ApplySuperscriptToFootnoteReference()
   With ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdFootnotesStory).Find
      .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleFootnoteReference)
      .Replacement.Font.Superscript = True
      .Format = True
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   End With
End Sub


Thanks for your reply! The script does nothing, sadly. Maybe it's my document that is, or the footnotes themselves that are, weirdly formatted or something? I'm working on someone's manuscript, so perhaps the author didn't create/format them correctly from the start?

Yes, that is possible. The code I have given you will work if the footnotes have been inserted correctly.
